# How to write CSV file on Remote server?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, httpwebrequest, streamwriter

I'm trying to write some output into .csv file which is at my server. I use following code but still there is no output in file.
means nothing is written.
my code is here

```
void WriteInRegister(DataRow userdata)
        {
            HttpWebRequest reqHTTP;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                reqHTTP = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://10.10.10.10/config/RequestPlacer.csv"));
                reqHTTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usename", "password");

                if (reqHTTP != null)
                {
                    reqHTTP.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    reqHTTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.File.UploadFile;
                }
                string postdata = (userdata[0].ToString() + ",MacId," + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()).ToString();
                byte[] text = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);

                reqHTTP.ContentLength = text.Length;

              /* WebClient wcClient = new WebClient();
                wcClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usename", "password");
                wcClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;*/
                //wcClient.OpenWrite(new Uri("http://10.10.10.10/config/RequestPlacer.csv"), postdata);


                //  string path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("http://10.10.10.10/config/RequestPlacer.csv");
                   reqHTTP.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
                   Stream writer = reqHTTP.GetRequestStream();
                  /* wcClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/csv");
                   wcClient.UploadString(new Uri("http://10.10.10.10/config/RequestPlacer.csv"), "POST", postdata);*/


                StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(writer);
                streamwriter.WriteLine(postdata);
                streamwriter.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exe.Message);
            }
        }
```

Exception is("The request was aborted: The request was canceled.")

Comment: You're not calling GetResponse on the request, so it can't complete. On which line does it throw the exception?

Comment: at last streamwriter.Close();

Comment: I was also tried WebClient but no result

Comment: Exception is("The request was aborted: The request was canceled.")

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that what you write to the stream doesn't match the length you indicated in the `Content-Length` header: because you use `streamwriter.WriteLine`, you also write a carriage return + line feed that is not counted in the content length you sent.

For instance, if your `postdata` is `"foo"`, `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata).Length` will return 3, but `streamwriter.WriteLine(postdata)` will actually write `"foo\r\n"`, which is 5 bytes.

You just need to use `Write` instead of `WriteLine` (or count the new line in the content length if you want to keep it)